# deploy local nginx server to public ubuntu 16.04

Tags: express, nginx, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

I am trying to **deploy my local nginx server** to the public. The nginx server runs as a **reverse proxy** to my **node express app** which is also running **locally on port 3000**. Therefore I have created a symbolic link from /etc/nginx/sites-available/express  TO   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/express, so my configuration file is called express and looks like this.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**express**

```
upstream express_servers{
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://express_servers;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

I have removed the default file from the sites-enabled folder and I have not changed my nginx.conf file which looks like this

/etc/nginx/**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

I also changed my firewall settings with ufw (uncomplicated firewall) to allow in http access (especially nginx). My ufw status looks like the following:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

    To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

when I am running load tests with wrk or loadtest(npm) everything seems to work fine. For example

```
wrk -t12 -c50 -d5s http://192.168.178.57/getCats/eng
```

so locally I can access the nginx server, but when I try to access the server from public with my Phone (3G/4G), I can't reach the server. What exactly did I miss ?

EDIT: I'm trying to access the service by **http://PUBLIC_IP_ADDR/getCats/eng**, not the local addr.

Comment: 192.168.0.0/16 is in private lan address space. so you can not access your website via cellar network. more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network . in another word: contact your ISP, buy i publish IP, or host your website in hosting services somewhere like aws ec2.

Comment: i just used the private lan address for the prupose of local load testing .... Actually im working with my public ip address. So you mean i actually need to buy sth like a license to be able to publish a service from my local machine ????? AWS EC2 is my plan B, but first i want to try to deploy the service from my local machine ...

Comment: you have to visit your website from your phone by visiting `http://PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS/getCats/eng` :D

Comment: Thats the way I'm already doing it. I edited the post, sry for being so inaccurate before ...

Comment: Take a look at your internet access device/router. Your router may not have the port open, or a static IP forwarded to your computer, or NAT is turned off. Your ISP might not allow incoming traffic either.

Comment: I have to agree with @jedifans. This looks more like a router configuration issue than anything else.

Comment: i will look into that today. hope so ...

Answer (score 3):

Your nginx config looks perfectly fine.

To be able to access your server from outside you need a public static IP from your ISP. Also ISP should not block incoming traffic to ports 80 and 443(in case you decide to go with https).

Then you probably have a LAN like this:

```
ISP <---> Router <---> Server
             ^
             |
             ----> your other devices
```

In this case public IP will be assigned to router, all other devices will have local private ips like `192.168.x.x/24`/`10.x.x.x/8`/`172.16.0.0/20`

You need to configure port forwarding to server's private ip from router. Depending on router's vendor this feature may be called `virtual server` or so and is usually found somewhere near WAN configuration. Set it up to forward TCP port 80 to server local port 80 and the same for 443.

Also you may need to configure server to static ip so that local ip address will not change

Comment: Your solution seems to be right at the first look, but It looks like my router is using a DS-Lite Tunnel, so there is a problem with connections from outside. I even cant reach the Server via ipv6 address: http://[IPV6]/getCats/eng. I changed my Port settings on the router to allow access via http.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put

```
listen *:80
```

in your file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/express

[nginx listen doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

I think it's not listening for requests from you ISP public IP as you have it now.

Comment: I thought that the asterisk is redundant, but still no success after trying it out.